# How to filter for an array, based on a glob like '*.rb'

Tags: ruby

Here is my data structure:

```
array = [

 ['foo.rb', 'file', '2432'],
 ['bar/', 'directory', '2048'],
 ['bla.yml', 'file', '10'],
 ['ble.rb', 'file', '2156']
]
```

Now I wish to find all .rb files.

My filter thus looks like this:

```
filter = '*.rb'
```

Is there a way to filter this properly on the array variable?

The result should be:

```
array = [
 ['foo.rb', 'file', '2432'],
 ['ble.rb', 'file', '2156']
]
```

If it were via Dir.glob() it would be easy, but this is an array-like
datastructure and I am a bit confused how I could easily 
filter on it.

Answer (score 1):

```
array.select{|x| x[0].end_with?(".rb") }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`File.fnmatch?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/File.html#method-c-fnmatch) to do shell-style filename globbing on any string:

```
files = [ [ 'foo.rb', 'file', '2432' ],
          [ 'bar/', 'directory', '2048' ],
          [ 'bla.yml', 'file', '10' ],
          [ 'ble.rb', 'file', '2156' ]
        ]

pattern = "*.rb"

files.select do |filename,|
  File.fnmatch?(pattern, filename)
end
# => [ [ 'foo.rb', 'file', '2432' ],
#      [ 'ble.rb', 'file', '2156' ] ]
```

Note the comma in `do |filename,|`. This is just syntactic sugar which discards all but the first element of the array, making the block equivalent to:

```
files.select do |arr|
  filename = arr[0]
  File.fnmatch?(pattern, filename)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>> array.find_all { |finfo| finfo[0].end_with?(".rb") }
=> [["foo.rb", "file", "2432"], ["ble.rb", "file", "2156"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the method [`File.extname`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/File.html#method-c-extname).

```
array = [
          ['foo.rb', 'file', '2432'],
          ['bar/', 'directory', '2048'],
          ['bla.yml', 'file', '10'],
          ['ble.rb', 'file', '2156']
        ]

array.select { |a| File.extname(a.first) == '.rb' }
# => [["foo.rb", "file", "2432"], ["ble.rb", "file", "2156"]]
```